# Erro neste código em PHP gera strings nulas ou vazias

Tags: php, javascript

É a minha primeira vez aqui. Estou com um problema com um código e queria ajuda de alguém para resolver

Eu peguei um código javascript e quis transformar ele em PHP, mas ao chamar a função ele não dá erro, mas também não retorna nada. E já quebrei a cabeça tentando ver aonde errei e não consigo....

O error_reporting da hospedagem está desabilitado. Tentei habilitar com .htaccess ou com o cPanel, (o que deduz que aparentemente não há erros aqui) e não obtive resultado.

Eu sei que isso não usa nada avançado de criptografia, Eu só preciso que ele embaralhe a String que eu quiser e desembaralhe ao tentar re-embaralhar o resultado, desde que tudo funcione dentro da cadeia de caracteres especificados na $ref dentro no PHP. Justamente isto não está funcionando e não sei mais o que fazer. Ajudem-me por favor!

Este é o código em JavaScript

```js
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- 
function encode (OrigString, CipherVal) {

       Ref="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz._~ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

        CipherVal = parseInt(CipherVal)

        var Temp=""

        for (Count=0; Count < OrigString.length; Count++) {

                var TempChar = OrigString.substring (Count, Count+1)

                var Conv = cton(TempChar)

                var Cipher=Conv^CipherVal

                Cipher=ntoc(Cipher)

                Temp += Cipher

        }

        return (Temp)

}

function cton (Char) {
        return (Ref.indexOf(Char));

}

function ntoc (Val) {
        return (Ref.substring(Val, Val+1))
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var EncodedText = encode ("Encode the text", 4);
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

Em javascript funciona normal, mas eu preciso que o mesmo código também funcione em PHP.

Este é o mesmo código acima que "tentei" converter para PHP:

```php
<?php
$ref="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz._~ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function encode ($string) {
 $temp=""; $cipherval = 4;

        for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
                $tempchar = substr ($string, $i, $i+1);
                $conv = cton($tempchar);
                $cipher=$conv^$cipherval;

                $cipher=ntoc($cipher);

                $temp .= $cipher;
        }
        return ($temp);
}

function cton ($char) { return (strpos($char, $ref)); }

function ntoc ($val) { return (substr($ref, $val, $val+1)); }

?>;

<?php echo "Texto: " . encode("Eu quero codificar esta frase!"); ?>
```

Era para aparecer qualquer coisa, mas se eu ponho isso em um arquivo, ex:  index.php e rodo no servidor, só aparece abaixo:

---

### Texto:

Comment: Reparei que não tem espaços em branco na cadeia de caracteres, mas já testei este código com uma string sem espaços em banco, e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

A função não está funcionando porque você colocou a variável `$ref` fora do escopo das suas funções. Você pode colocar ela dentro da função `encode()` ou passar ela como parâmetro.

```
function encode ($string) {
    $ref="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz._~ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $temp=""; $cipherval = 4;

    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $tempchar = substr ($string, $i, $i+1);
        $conv = cton($tempchar, $ref);
        $cipher = $conv^$cipherval;

        $cipher = ntoc($cipher, $ref);

        $temp .= $cipher;
    }
    return ($temp);
}

function cton ($char, $ref) { 
    return (strpos($char, $ref)); 
}

function ntoc ($val, $ref) { 
    return (substr($ref, $val, $val+1)); 
}


echo "Texto: " . encode("Eu quero codificar esta frase!");
```

Declarei a variável `$ref` dentro da função `encode()` e passei ela como parâmetro para as funções `cton()` e `ntoc()`.